# Disable default sound when showing error notification

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using NotifyIcon class to show the popup. How can I disable default sound when I'm showing error popup using windows notification area? I need to play my own sound, from resources, but I don't know how to temporarily disable sound which is defined in windows theme.

My code sample:

```
    public void Notify()
    {
        if (_icon != null)
            return;

        if (!Settings.Default.EnableTrayNotifications)
            return;

        _icon = CreateNotifyIcon(LoadIcon());
        _icon.Visible = true;
        _icon.ShowBalloonTip(Settings.Default.MinimumNotificationInterval);
    }

    private NotifyIcon CreateNotifyIcon(Stream iconStream)
    {
        var icon = new NotifyIcon
                    {
                        Icon = new Icon(iconStream),
                        BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error,
                        BalloonTipTitle = "Sometext",
                        BalloonTipText = "Sometext"
                    };
        icon.BalloonTipClicked += (s,a) => ShowWindow();
        icon.BalloonTipClosed += (s,a) => Cleanup();
        return icon;
    }
```

Thanks for cooperation.

Comment: How are you showing your error popup?

Comment: As I told, I'm using NotifyIcon class from WinForms, initialize it and call ShowBalloonTip method.

Comment: Glad I asked -- you didn't tell us any of that the first time around (no WinForms tag, no code sample, no reference to balloon tips). For all I knew "showing error popup" could have meant you were showing a MessageBox. Next time, consider showing a code sample the first time around -- that goes a long way toward communicating the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable default sound. You can create your own forms and play sounds.
See [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/taskbarnotifier.aspx)  or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_TaskbarNotifier.aspx) for ex.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to invent the wheel and create my own window. Any other ideas?

Comment: Someone has invented the wheel for you. See the links in my answer. Or google for `taskbar notifier c#` etc.